# Get the range of Appointments from Exchange with Office AddIn

Tags: asp.net, exchangewebservices

I create an User Property through an AddIn for Outlook.
I set the property like this:

```
public const string UP_VB = "up.test";
...
item.UserProperties.Add(
                UP_VB,                          // Name
                OlUserPropertyType.olYesNo,     // Type
                true);
...
```

And I retrieve it like this:

```
private readonly ExtendedPropertyDefinition _extendedProp =
        new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings,
            UserPropertyHelper.UP_VB, MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
...
Appointment appointmentDetailed = Appointment.Bind(exchangeService, appt.Id, 
      new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, _extendedProp) 
      { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text });
```

But when i check the value of the extended property. Doesn't have the value in it.

When I read It from the User Property the value it's fine, but when I read it from the EWS i get no value.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work okay but I would suggest you look at the Items involved using a Mapi editor like Outlookspy or MFCMapi. You should be able to find the property you have set using the OOM and check the PropertyName and PropertyType matches what you have defined in EWS.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Hi, I found out that the UserProperty It's not the same property I get from the Extended Properties its not the same. Can you tell me how to save the value then? thanks

Comment: Just use the PropertyAccessor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862751.aspx eg item.PropertyAccessor .SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/MyProp",true);

Comment: I try that and get: The property "schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/MyProp" cannot be parsed or has an invalid format. I even put http:// to the property and don't get an error, but dont get the value either.

Comment: If you use a MAPI editor what do you see ? you should be able to get the DSAL for the properties your setting. item in this context in the appointment item right ?

Comment: Witch MAPI editor? Haven't use one, and the context it's: The item for saving with VSTO. For reading I get the items in a range of dates with EWS then I get the same item.

Comment: Either MFCMapi or OutlookSpy will work, without a MAPI editor you won't be able to tell what's is happening, this will let you see all the properties available on an Item. If you going to be doing any Outlook/Exchange programming learn to use one (its easy) and will save you a lot time

Comment: I install Outlook Spy, and I see there was two User Properties, but cannot find the MAPI Property. With MFCMapi cannot find the Appointment Item. And In the properties of the user I don't see the property I created. To be honest. I don't think yo can comunicate EWS with VSTO. At least that's why this is making me believe.

Comment: With MFCMapi I find the property, but for the user, not the Appointment and his value was: Err: MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: >> I don't think yo can comunicate EWS with VSTO ..   That is wrong both the OOM and EWS are just API's for accessing items and both have access to any properties (why use EWS at all in a VSTO plugin you should be doing everything with the OOM). You really need to post all of your OOM code if you setting a property on Meeting and sending to attendees the properties get stripped you can workaround this by using X-header etc https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08ecce0a-be0a-4d42-9bbd-7d1691b8abde/using-propertyaccessor-to-set-and-get-properties-in-a-meeting-request?forum=vsto

Comment: Ok If I can do all with VSTO, there's a way to get all the meetings for a room with VSTO in a range of dates? Thanks

Comment: Sure just use a filter see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg619398.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I have to suspend that activity, but thats a good aproach. I let you know when I retake it how it goes. Can you hlep me to update the question to: Get the range of Appointments from Exchange with Office AddIn? Thanks.